# Not seeing variables in an Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, variables, scope

I have searched the questions and found some that are very close but I'm still doing something wrong. I want to use a variable for the worksheet name in the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim wrkPro As String
Dim wrkFFIS As String

Sub MainLoop()
'*************************************************************************************************************************
'*
'*************************************************************************************************************************
    Dim FFISno As Range         '* Admustments
    Dim ProTracksno As Range    '* Contracts
    Dim FFISnx As String        '* Corrected Contract Number
    Dim PTdte As Date
    Dim FFISdte As Date
    Dim orow As Integer
    Dim frow As Integer
    Dim prow As Integer
    Dim rngRange As Range

    orow = 2                    '* Output Row
    frow = 2                    '* FFIS Row
    prow = 7                    '* ProTracks Row

    '* Set Worksheet for input ...
    wrkPro = CStr(Sheets("SysCtrl").Cells(4, 2).Value) & "ProTracts"
    wrkFFIS = CStr(Sheets("SysCtrl").Cells(4, 2).Value) & "FFIS"

    '* Clear the Recap Sheet
    Sheets("Recap").Range("A2, B5000").ClearContents
    '* Sheets("Recap").Rows(CStr(orow) & ":" & CStr(Worksheets("Recap").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)).ClearContents
    '* Sheets("Recap").Cells(1, 1).Select

BeginLoop:
    '* Do until EOF on ProTracks Table
    Do While Sheets(wrkPro).Cells(prow, 7) <> "" And Sheets(wrkFFIS).Cells(frow, 4) <> ""
```

When I run it, I'm getting the subscript out of range error. I have checked and the variable has the correct value in it but it is not using it as a string in the Do While.

I tried adding Char(34) before and after the string and changing the Dim to a Public as suggested in other posts but no joy.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Carter

Comment: At a decent glance your code likes solid in terms of how you want to get the sheetname. I would do a test to make sure the sheetname for the variable for `wrkPro/wrkFFIS` is coming out exactly like the sheetname in your workbook. So after you set the string for each place a `debug.print wrkPro` and `debug.print wrkFFIS` and make sure it the name exists in your WB as is. Also, try removing the `Cstr` wrapper?

Comment: Try debugging your code: set a breakpoint in the line starting with `wrkPro =` (press F9 in this row), and run the code. Once it stops here, you can execute each line by line with F8. In the Immediate window (Ctrl-G) you can check your variable (`Debug.Print wrkPro`, in the Locals window (View->Locals) you can see it directly. Make sure that the content of `wrkPro`matches exactly with your sheet name - you can check with `Debug.Print Sheet1.Name = wrkPro` - just replace `Sheet1` with the Code name of your worksheet - you can see this in the VBA editor in the list left.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Worksheets**(wrkPro).Cells instead of your Sheets(wrkPro).Cells - Sheets() references a sheet by index, i.e. integer, e.g. Sheets(1).Cells etc.
**Worksheets**(wrkPro).Cells string variable as a name should be acceptable.

Comment: This does not seem to be correct. `Sheets(String)` exists, too, and works just as well.

Comment: @KekuSemau perhaps you're right, but `Sub test() Sheets("1").Range("A1").Select End Sub` returned me **the subscript out of range error**, while `Sheets(1).` compiles just fine. Excel 2007 - just in case.

Comment: Yes, the string parameter must be the _name_ of a sheet.

Comment: My bad, you're correct: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select` works fine! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Tried Worksheets instead of Sheets but I'm still getting the same error. I guess I could use year to get a relative sheet number but that means the sheets have to stay in the same order. Any thing else?

Comment: I figured this thing out. The sheet names started with the year and ended with the datatype. Example: 2006ProTracts. When I turned the elements around and put Protracts first and 2006 second, it worked as it should. The leading number was causing it to interpret it as a number. Thanks to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
Sheets("Recap").Range("A2, B5000").ClearContents
```

to this:

```
Sheets("Recap").Range("A2:B5000").ClearContents
```